# Android:How to make Radio button non changable by user?

Tags: android

I have a RadioGroup with two radio button's in it. And based on some internal calculation's I am selecting one of them. I want to make them non changeable by the user from UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RadioButton btn=(RadioButton)findviewById(R.id.yourButtonIdInRadioGroup);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your layout file set `android:enabled="false"`

Just like this

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:enabled="false"/>
```